# How do I use 'amicable' in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I've made some sentences with the word 'amicable':

> *An **amicable** family*.
> *Our relationships are **amicable***.
> *We get on **amicably***.

Does it sound normal for a native English speaker?
If my sentences are wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: If you're concerned with the grammar of your sentences (the first one is a phrase,to be precise), then you shouldn't be. Those are correct as far as grammar and syntax go. If your concern is _whether I should have chosen **amiable** instead of **amicable**_, again you need not be concerned. You have used the right word there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I’ve meant something another. Are they enough common for native speakers? Do you use this word “amicable” as I used it in my examples? Or would you prefer to chose something else in this context?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the word itself. But then, it depends on what you're trying to say. As such, there is no problem whatever with your examples.

Comment: _Friendly_ would be more colloquial. The Latin-derived _amicable_ has a slightly literary flavour to it.

Comment: I'll note that "amicable" is fairly rare in the US, and is likely to be considered slightly hoity-toity.

Comment: Guys, thanks! Can you flesh it out a little? In which situations and cases it would be appropriate and soundable to use this word?

Answer (score 0):

The most common usage of "amicable" is to indicate that a situation is friendly and peaceable when it could easily be hostile.

Consider the example from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/amicable?s=t):

> adjective
> characterized by or showing goodwill; friendly; peaceable:
> an amicable settlement.

A "settlement"? This is about an argument or legal battle - something that is disagreeable.

Or if you asked someone about another person and they said:

> "We are on amicable terms"

It implies a potentially conflicting relationship, although not at the moment.

The standard word "friendly" is more colloquial, and doesn't have these implications about disagreement.

The Latin-derived amicable has a literary flavor to it, and isn't frequently used in casual conversations.

> An amicable family.

Doesn't sound idiomatic.

> We get on amicably.

Could be a literary way to say "we are good acquaintances", as written by Mark Twain.

> How do I use 'amicable' in a sentence?

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=amicable) offers dozens of example sentences with the target word.

> The provincial commissions are the first point of appeal in case of failure to reach an *amicable* settlement.

> d) to encourage *amicable* solutions with a view to obtaining voluntary payment of maintenance, where suitable by use of mediation

> As mentioned above, the best interests of the child are likely to be best served if an *amicable* solution can be reached.